# twig variable inside a function

Tags: php, arrays, twig, slim

I am having trouble working around with twig.

I pass a `$labelz` var on twig, and this `$labelz` is an array of the form `label[0][left]`, `label[1][left]`, ... `label[2][left]` so on.

This array, `$labelz` is actually a _POST var, so when I do some "validation", i want to echo the values stored on this array again back to the form. Hence, I loop it on twig. I can successfully echo the stored value back in a input form using

```
{% for key, label in labelz %}
<input type="text" name="label[{{ key }}][left]" value="{{ labelz[key]['left'] }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Now, here is my problem, I am using this function

```
{% if errors.has('VARIABLE') %}
   {{ errors.first('VARIABLE') }}
{% endif %}">
```

to check if there's an error passed to the page (using `errors.has()`), then echo the error message if it has (using `errors.first()`) . Now, with those function I want to do the same to `$labelz` so I tried using this:

```
{% for key, label in labelz %}
   {% if errors.has(labelz[key]['left']) %}
      {{ errors.first(labelz[key]['left']) }}
   {% endif %}`
{% endfor %}
```

but it fails, because as you can see, and note `key` is a forloop variable of twig, and i have no idea how to make this work. Please help thanks!

Comment: Could you show us the definitions of `errors.has()` and `errors.first()`?

Comment: @alexw its actually from https://github.com/alexgarrett/violin anyway I already solved the question by using `~`, sorry to bother,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns our `~` solved my problem, it allows me to concatenate string on twig.

Thanks!